# SQL Server 2000 xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, xp-cmdshell

Using SQL Server 2000 I am trying to use this command in Query Analyzer

```
xp_cmdshell 'del c:\delete-me-file.txt'
```

and I'm getting this error:

> Server: Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
>   Could not find stored procedure 'xp_cmdshell'.

Basically I want to delete this file from the system... what command do I need to run to do this?

Comment: Please tell us why it's not sufficient to use "DEL" from the command line. In other words, why do you need to do that from inside of SQL Server?

Comment: because I am running an automated bulk import in .sql and would like remove the file after import.

Comment: And since you're using SQL Server 2000, you can't use SSIS. Ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be in the context of the `master` database or prefix the extended stored procedure with the db name.

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'del c:\delete-me-file.txt'
```

If this command succeeds it would indicate that the SQL Server service account probably has too many permissions however.